# Why do I get ReadTimeout errors even with low load using Locust?

Tags: locust

I'm running load-tests with Locust.  I have two user-types that inherit from the HttpUser class, and they both call the same endpoints with the same parameters using the Python Requests library.

Type A users make calls more often and Type B users make calls less often, but pass longer query-strings.

No matter how many users I spawn (very few, or very many) usually once the test has been running for ten to 15 minutes, the same error starts occurring, for just one User-type (User Type B):

```
ReadTimeout(ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'server.name.com',port=443):Read timed out. (read=timeout=None)",),)'
```

User Type A (on high and low load) continues making all requests with no failures.

Again, both user types are making the same calls, and all the individual calls have been QA'ed (they all work).  It's only under load tests where they seem to fail intermittently.

Here is a view into some of the code.  Below is a task, an intermediary function, and an implementation of one of my api calls.  My code repeats this structure for all calls, for both users.

Task

```
@task(5)
def get_one_audio_file(self):
    self.do_task(self.get_one_audio_file_request)

def do_task(self, a_task):
        a_task()

def get_one_audio_file_request(self):
    path = files/audio/
    self.client.get(path, name="files/audio", headers=headers, verify=False)
```

I'm at a loss to explain what's going on here.
If I run a load test with Type A users only, they test runs fine.
Any ideas?

Comment: Check RAM, CPU, and network usage on the machine generating the load. Do your Type B users start timing out after the same amount of time every time or does it vary by the number you run? Can you run a single Type B for an extended period of time? Have you checked server side metrics (RAM/CPU/network) and logs to make sure your server can handle what you're trying to do?

Comment: Try manually making the request that fails outside of locust (when locust starts failing). The most likely cause is that your actual system under test is overloaded or is throtteling somehow (flood protection?).

Comment: Also check out https://github.com/locustio/locust/wiki/FAQ#increase-my-request-raterps

Comment: @Solowalker it's very strange, even at very low load, eventually errors only occur for Type B users.  Type A users have zero failures.  The type B users do seem to start timing out after the same amount of time on every run.  I cannot run type B for an extended period without failures, but conversely, Type A can indeed run for an extended period without failure.  Server side metrics all appear stable